# how to find intersections from OpenStreetMap？

Tags: intersection, openstreetmap

How to extract intersections in the OpenStreetMap？ I need the longitude and latitude of the intersections, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There has been a similar question [here](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15442/detection-of-intersections-in-the-maps). There is no direct API call to retrieve intersections. But you can query all ways in a given bounding box (for example directly via the [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) or via the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)) and look for nodes shared by two or more ways as explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try the GeoNames `findNearestIntersectionOSM` API:
http://api.geonames.org/findNearestIntersectionOSMJSON?lat=37.451&lng=-122.18&username=demo

The input is lng and lat of location and the response contains lng and lat of nearest intersection:

```
{"intersection":{...,"lng":"-122.1808293","lat":"37.4506505"}}
```

It is provided by [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html), but seems to be based on [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API)

Answer (score 3):

As @scai perfectly explained, **you have to process the raw OSM data yourself to find intersection nodes of ways**.

Instead of writing your own program, you can try different algorithms first using the [OverpassAPI](http://overpass-turbo.eu/).

- Dependent on which kind of ways you are interested in, add the types of ways which should not count as intersection to the *regv* attribute (at two script sections). The type of ways can be found here: [highway tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway).
- The BoundingBox is the part of the map you are viewing on the Overpass-tourbo Website.
- *The script is based on a scripted linked in [another question's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18385182/5815054) but I rewrote it to make it more readable and added comments (both here and in the original reply).*

**Sample Script:**

```
<!-- Only select the type of ways you are interested in -->
<query type="way" into="relevant_ways">
  <has-kv k="highway"/>
  <has-kv k="highway" modv="not" regv="footway|cycleway|path|service|track"/>
  <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
</query>

<!-- Now find all intersection nodes for each way independently -->
<foreach from="relevant_ways" into="this_way">  

  <!-- Get all ways which are linked to this way -->
  <recurse from="this_way" type="way-node" into="this_ways_nodes"/>
  <recurse from="this_ways_nodes" type="node-way" into="linked_ways"/>
  <!-- Again, only select the ways you are interested in, see beginning -->
  <query type="way" into="linked_ways">
    <item set="linked_ways"/>
    <has-kv k="highway"/>
    <has-kv k="highway" modv="not" regv="footway|cycleway|path|service|track"/>
  </query>

  <!-- Get all linked ways without the current way --> 
  <difference into="linked_ways_only">
    <item set="linked_ways"/>
    <item set="this_way"/>
  </difference>
  <recurse from="linked_ways_only" type="way-node" into="linked_ways_only_nodes"/>

  <!-- Return all intersection nodes -->
  <query type="node">
    <item set="linked_ways_only_nodes"/>
    <item set="this_ways_nodes"/>
  </query>
  <print/>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have imported OSM data to postgis postgresql with osm2pgsql, you can query intersections like this:

```
SELECT
  ST_AsText(st_intersection(a.way, b.way)) AS way
FROM
  (select * from planet_osm_line where highway='service') AS a,
  (select * from planet_osm_line where highway='footway') AS b
WHERE
  ST_Intersects(a.way, b.way)
  AND a.osm_id != b.osm_id;
```