# Filtering intersections to (4-way intersections, T-junctions, and other ) using Overpass API in a given bounding box

Tags: openstreetmap, intersection, overpass-api

There is a script [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241377/how-to-find-intersections-from-openstreetmap) that can process the data from OSM to detect intersections in a given bounding box. It works by getting all the ways in a given bounding box and then finding other ways that share common nodes with these roads. Here is the query that does that,

```
way
  ["highway"]
  ["highway"!~"footway|cycleway|path|service|track|proposed"]
  (, , , )
  ->.relevant_ways;
foreach.relevant_ways->.this_way{
  node(w.this_way)->.this_ways_nodes;
  way(bn.this_ways_nodes)->.linked_ways;
  way.linked_ways
    ["highway"]
    ["highway"!~"footway|cycleway|path|service|track|proposed"]
    ->.linked_ways;
    (
        .linked_ways->.linked_ways;
        -
        .this_way->.this_way;
    )->.linked_ways_only;
    node(w.linked_ways_only)->.linked_ways_only_nodes;
    node.linked_ways_only_nodes.this_ways_nodes;
    out;
}
```

This query returns all kinds of intersections (4-way intersections, T-junctions, ... ).

**Question**: 
Is there a way to further filter out the intersection to 4-way intersections and T-junctions?

One idea I have is to check if the common node is an endpoint of one the ways, which makes the intersection and if the common node is in the middle of the road it will be a 4-way intersection. But I am not sure how to write a query that does this.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I'd say no. You probably need some post processing on your own based on the query result you've got.

Comment: I will try to do that, thanks for the reply.